# TornadoFX scatterchart updating

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

I have a scatter chart with some points in it. I want to update the position of the  points when i press a button. I have the following code:

```
class Point(var x: Int, var y: Int)

class TestView : View("TestView") {

val points = listOf(Point(0,1),Point(1,1)).observable()

override val root = borderpane {
    center {
        scatterchart("test", NumberAxis(), NumberAxis()) {
            series("Group 1") {
                points.forEach{
                    data(it.x, it.y)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    bottom {
        button("Button") {
            action {
                points[0].x = 5
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

When i press the button, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `data(it.x, it.y)` while looping over your `points` list, you're actually adding data to the chart. Changing the list you iterated over after the fact will not have any effect on the data points you've added earlier.

Each `Series` has an `ObservableList<XYChart.Data<Number, Number>>` called `data` where the actual data for the chart series is stored. You can bind to the `dataProperty` of a series if you want to automatically update the chart as these data points change, or alternatively you can manipulate the `data` list directly to get the same effect without adding binding/listeners.